# Using one switch to control multiple circuits

Tags: relay

I have a sectional couch with electrical recline. Each section reclines with a separate button. I would like to add a toggle switch that would allow the recline buttons to make all sections recline at the same time. Each section has a 29V DC power supply (1.8A) going to a motor and then push buttons to recline forward/backwards.

I've simplified the problem for now to 2 sections and one recline direction as I think I can generalize it from there.

I have a software background so I started by using boolean logic to understand the solution, which gave me:

Q_A = A + BT

Q_B = B + AT

A = switch on section A

B = switch on section B

T = toggle between individual recline and combined recline

Q_A = output to motor A

Q_B = output to motor B

So my first instinct was to just build that with relays:

[image: Circuit with relays]

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to solve this problem?
2. If relays are a good approach, is there a better way than the circuit above?

Comment: Relays are fine. Why not arrange to use the existing 29 V supply for the new relay coils, though? Surely the extra relays coils won't overtax it.

Comment: @jonk yeah the 9V was fairly arbitrary, but also I thought it would be easier to find relays that need a 9V coil voltage vs 29V (does that even exist?)

Comment: So far it seems that your wiring diagram may have a few bugs, RLY_T has no -9 connection for the coil, Relay Q_B has the coil shorted.

Comment: @Nedd Just typos. ;) The schematic does get the point across, with or without the mistakes. But good catch, too!

Comment: @NicWolfe Relays work over a range. You could likely use 24 V to 32 V relays and get away with it. Worth trying, anyway. Also, you can add circuitry to mate them better, I suppose.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just short the outputs of buttons A an B with the toggle switch? Do you suspect that one push button couldn't power both motor relays?

Comment: I think this could be implemented with just diodes in a wired-OR configuration. The T switch would be connected to two diodes going to both motors. However, having two 29 volt supplies may dictate keeping the Q_A and Q_B relays, and the diodes would drive the coils.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as this for two sections and one recline direction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB9rkc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: OK, you beat me by 4 minutes, (identical answer and wiring diagram withdrawn).  However I'll add this:  The recliner must have a forward and reverse recline circuit so it may be required that a double pole toggle switch be used, (as the added shorting switch), that way both the recline and un-recline switching circuits can be shorted together on separate poles of the switch.

Comment: @Nedd - Hi Nedd, I suppose luck was with me! I've limited my answer to the simplified version of the problem ("I've simplified the problem for now to 2 sections and one recline direction as I think I can generalize it from there.")

Answer (score 0):

Only need two relays, here's [one on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/183732591020) that would work for one, and another switch C to connect input lines A and B, to simplify circuit above.

For three motors, just three relays and four switches, maybe three push buttons and one [3PST toggle switch](https://www.ebay.com/itm/372387256952).

Also the 29V supply would work on the relay linked above.

Comment: There is a schematic editing tool available when you write/edit an an answer in EESE. While one can make a messy diagram using any tool, I think you would have a better chance at a clean schematic using this tool (CircuitLab) than using MS Paint.